# Does INSTALL_REFERRER receiver still work on Android Oreo?

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I test my app on Galaxy S8+, Oreo 8.0.0 with [referrerSender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsflyer.referrerSender). There is something wrong, and it likes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI1su.png)

It works well on another phone(Android 5.1.1)

Comment: why do not use new google install referrer module? `compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'`

Comment: @MaximShoustin, AppsFlyer does use the installreferrer. But the SDK Document also request to add the SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Worth to check that your test-app is not killed but stays in background (that can cause to timeout)

Comment: @MaximShoustin My App is alive, but can not receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with Android Oreo 8.0.0 or above: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000427963-Android-Generating-a-Non-Organic-Install

Please follow these steps:
(1) Ensure that your device is whitelisted on AF dashboard
(2) Ensure that you do not have the app installed on your device
(3) Click on the tracking link https://app.appsflyer.com/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME?pid=MEDIA_SOURCE&advertising_id=YOUR_GOOGLE_ADVERTISING_ID (you will be redirected to the Google Play but you can ignore it)
(4) Install the APK build
(5) Launch the app
(6) The dashboard should show one non-organic install with media source = MEDIA_SOURCE

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Thanks - how's that different to the normal process the OP will have tried? Which part specifically will fix this for Oreo?

Comment: Now I still don't know why Android Integration Test App not working with Android 8.0.0. So I use manually solution to test my SDK Integration and it works :D